# Drawing 95% credible intervals for my bayesian predictions along with the Points from the actual observed value of the response variable

Tags: r

The response variable for my dataset is comprised of observations Y[1], Y[2], ...., Y[49]. I came up with a Bayesian Hierarchical Model to make Bayesian predictions for Y[50]. I also have MCMC samples for Y[1],...,Y[49], which I can use to assess the overall fit of my Bayesian model by comparing them with the actual values of Y[1], Y[2], ...., Y[49].

Is there any way that I can draw the caterpillar plots of my Bayesian Predictions from the MCMC object of the Hierarchical Model along with the points that stands for actual observed Y's from my original dataset on R?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

First you need to extract your confidence intervals for each $Y_i$ . (usually this is done with quantile function if you're not using a standard S3 object).

Then you create the following df:

```
df <- data_frame(
           obs = seq(from = 1,
                              to = 49,
                              by = 1),
           lower = q1,
           upper = q2,
           estimate = estimate,
           actual = actual)
```

Then you go:

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(x = obs)) +
              geom_line(aes(y = actual)) +
              geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper, y = estimate)) +
              coord_flip()
```

If you're doing hierarchical models I really recommend using *rstanarm* package which is compatible with the tidybayes library (which produces automatic caterpillar plots).